# How to put element on top of other which is in higher layer in Cocos2D?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, layer

I have a gameplay scene with it's own layer and other layer which handles all the HUD information (hp bars, turn counts and so forth). I have put the HUD layer on top of the gameplay layer. The problem is, I have some elements in gameplay scene that I would like to be on top of the HUD elements. I can't seem to be able to do that by just specificating higher z value on a sprite for example.

Is there a solution for this and what would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - add these elements either to the HUD layer or to a third layer above both.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that would be one way, but I guess then there isn't any other way of doing it?

Comment: Nope, that's the only option.